# iPhone - iOS5: Geolocation on phonegap

Tags: iphone, geolocation, cordova, ios5

I updated the iPhone to iOS5 but now the geolocation doesn't work in 
my Phonegap application. 
I also have a webapp with the same code and geolocation works here. 
Did you have the same problem? 
Any advice? 
Thanks! 
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have had the same problem, although i updated my phone ios, xcode sdk and phonegap to 1.1. now for some 'random' reason, on my code the getCurrentLocation gets stuck triggering in loop. i'm fairly sure this has to do with the new phonegap framework, because even on the 4.3 emulator it still behaves the same, which it didnt before with phonegap 1.0.

my solution was to use the watchPosition and manually clear it after the first iteration, which sounds even better since phonegap 1.0 had some issues with getting your geolocation on the first run.